Vite Rails and JS modules in views
I was working on migrating from webpacker to vite and it has been pretty seemless overall, just have one question in regards to using imported JS in a view.
Currently have an entrypoint -- lets just say it looks like this:
import { testMethod } from '~/src/js/testfunctions.js'
import '~/src/css/test.scss'
etc...

The js file structure is like this:
export function testMethod() {
  ..code here
}

And in my view, I have a script tag at the bottom of the file, trying to call my method:
%script{type: 'module'}
  :plain
    testMethod();

but the method is unavailable to call from the view for whatever reason -- testMethod() is not defined error in the console.

In my entrypoint, would I have to make the methods globally accessible?
For example if I was including the testMethod() function:
import { testMethod } from '../' would I just put in the entrypoint: window.testMethod = testMethod ?

Yes, but there is a much better way of going about this. If what you want to acheive is to just have your code run on certain pages you can just add some data attributes to the body tag <body data-action="<%= action %>" data-controller="<%= controller %>"> or meta tags or whatever and then setup an event handler which fires when the page is loaded/reloaded and checks if that is present. That lets you keep the concerns separated and avoids polluting the global scope. This can also be acheived pretty easily with with a stimulus controller.

I wrote a gem very long ago that I haven't maintained that shows the basic approach. https://github.com/maxcal/pagescript
